# Determine the part of chrono durations

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I would like to compute which part of one duration contains in another duration. There is [standard implementation for integers (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4), but it gives me `0` (due to integer divison) for the following example:

```
auto s = 1s;
auto ms = 200ms;
std::cout << ms / s; // 0, but I want 0.2 here
```

Is there a more elegant and generic way to compute a such value instead of the following [ugly solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SZnV6x1lyjnK6XXp)?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;    

    auto s = 1s;
    auto ms = 200ms;

    const auto part = 1. * ms.count() / std::chrono::duration_cast<decltype(ms)>(s).count();

    std::cout << part << '\n';
}
```

One smart way is to use `1. / (s / ms);`, but it's not fit for any duration types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `double` based duration.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;    
    using my_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>;

    my_seconds s = 1s;
    my_seconds ms = 200ms;

    std::cout << ms / s << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Using the old types with a cast also works `std::chrono::duration_cast<my_seconds>(ms) / s`. Thank you!

Comment: @alexolut:  `ms` will implicitly convert to `my_seconds`, no need to use `duration_cast`:  `my_seconds{ms} / s`.  It is best to reserve `duration_cast` for only those times you wish to force a truncation.